# Getting HTTP 411 when specifying Content-Length

Tags: http, post, http-status-code-411

I am getting an HTTP 411 error when testing a POST request.  I am not an expert with APIs but I feel like I'm not a complete newbie, either.  I am using Advanced Rest Client to test the request because I don't have code generating it.  I am trying to replicate a process that will be sent in by a customer's process.

I have looked in as many places as I could find, including here, for the answer.  Basically what I found is two answers:

- you have to have the Content-Length header with the length of the request
- you can put in the Content-Length header with a length of 0

I have tried both of these options and many other combinations of headers that I thought might work but to no avail.  I always end up with a 411 except when I tried to put in something with Authentication.  Then I got a "Go away, you can't be here." :)

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is too general. Add some more details such as where you run your request from localhost/remote host, how you calculate the content length etc.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, ino.  I am running this from a remote host.  I calculated the length by pasting the payload into Notepad++ and checking the length.  I'm sorry but I'm not sure what else to specify.  I can certainly answer questions.  Maybe I'm more of a newbie than I thought...